# How to make a "system" screenshot with ButtonMapper

Tags: hardware, buttons, screenshots

Since a recent update of ButtonMapper the functionality to make a "system screenshot" (if you have root) seemed to be replaced by a "app screenshot", which is limited in some apps as Instagram of Snapchat and also makes a very annoying clicker sound. I understand non rooted users prefer this over nothing. But I like to have my "system screenshot" back when I long press the Volume Down button.

I bought the Pro version of ButtonMapper and I have root access. Can someone please tell me how I can assign my "system screenshot" functionality back to long press Volume Down in Button Mapper? I miss it so hard.

Answer (score 1):

the developer build this in but you have to know...
if you want a system screenshot instead of a limited app screenshot
do the following in ButtonMapper:

1. be sure to have root access
2. press the 3 dots
3. select "check for root"
4. now assign the screenshot functionality again to the desired button
5. ButtonMapper is making a "system screenshot" instead of an "app screenshot"!